# Как реализовать логаут?

Tags: flutter

Пишу приложение на Flutter используя Provider для хранения состояния и DI, но столкнулся с такой проблемой как логаут. У меня больше десяти экранов, но не могу придумать простого механизма для очистки состояний всех экранов. В нативной разработке это было доволи просто, если не было оговорена другое, то после основных действий я перезапускал приложение, тут же нет такой возможности. Даже если это реализовать это на уровне нативной, то вот для iOSтакое не реализуемо.

Может я что-то не дочитался в документации Provider или есть какие-то другие решения.

P.S. Видел пару плагинов для этих целей, но:

- не совсем понял принцип их реализации;
- не хотелось бы тянуть в проект плагин ради таких целей.

Answer (score 2):

Provider хороший инструмент для DI, но не является полноценным стейт менеджером (на одну из причин вы как раз и попали).

[Способ через GlobalKey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777054/8387227) (hard-reset с сохранением поддерева):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider(
    key: ObjectKey(someIdentifier),
    builder: (_) => Foo(),
    child: SomeSubtree(
      key: GlobalObjectKey(context),
    ),
  );
}
```

Через общий интерфейс (добавить интерфейс и метод очистки, вызывать вручную для каждого сейта) + отдельный отдельный Provider для управления:

```
abstract class ProviderInterface with ChangeNotifier {
  void clean();
}

class ProviderImplementation with ChangeNotifier implements ProviderInterface {
  @override
  void clean(){...}
}
```

Comment: Вариант через ключ у меня не работает. Вот я храню ключ, инжектю его в модель через которую выполняю логаут и дальше что? Пробовал его подменять. Опять же пробовал через ObjectKey с глобал вообще беда. Можно как-то по подробнее?

Comment: Для каждого экрана это конечно круто, но мне такой вариант не особо нравится т.к: - у нужно вызивать для каждого экрана; - нужно следить что бы при изменении этого экрана, все поля были добавлены в метод.

Comment: @Valeriy к сожалению я с Provider так плотно не работал (использовал его только для DI), по этому больше ничем помочь не смогу. Дал вам направление в котором нужно капать...

Comment: @Valeriy скиньте ссылку на плагины, возможно там есть решение